# Is there a callback function for when "Done" is pressed in a Youtube-embedded UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've followed and implemented the following example to embed a Youtube video into my app:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

This basically opens the YouTube app in the device and when the user presses "Done" switches the canvas back to my own app. Anyone know if there is a callback method for when this happens.  I want to continue playing my app's music which was cut off during the YouTube video playing in the youtube app (I definitely know how to start the music but I need to know when the user has pressed "Done").

Thanks for any help pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is on the iPhone/iPod Touch only, I suspect `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewDidAppear:` will be called on the view controller being shown. You should be able to use these methods to resume playing your app's music.  On the iPad, these methods are not called if the view controller is a modal view that isn't full-screen.

See: [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16)

Comment: Yes it is for the iPhone but alas these methods weren't called. When a Youtube video embedded UIWebView  is tapped by the user, the current app slides out of view but is still playing in the background and the YouTube App is opened to play the video.  Once the user presses "Done" in the video interface the YTube app closes and the first app still playing in the background slides back into view. There must be some callback that lets me know the YTube app closed and my app has come back. Hmm, I'm stumped.